# Can we have an array of Ether in Solidity?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

My ultimate goal is to have an array of token, e.g.

```
 mapping (address => x) token_balance;
```

where x is of type a float/double.

As far as I'm aware, Solidity does not support float/double values.

However, wie or ether etc supported and wie is a fraction of Ether. So, if we can have an array of Ether, then we might be able to handle float/double. Because, for instance, we can add one wei to token_balance["address"]+=wei;

**Question** 1: In Solidity, can we have any array of Ether, like:

```
  mapping (address => Ether) balances
```

---

Why do I need an array of float? Because, the token holders will be charged this amount: x= t.10/T, for doing certain actions; where t is total the token a token holder has, and T is the total number of token all token holders have. So x is a float value, even if t and T are integer values.

Comment: All computations for ether are done with integers (the same is done for tokens). It is called fixed point decimal you take 1 ether = 10^18 and the operate considering that, so you have 18 decimals. But obviously you cannot have a fraction of 1 wei.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for the comment. If I understood your point correctly, if we convert it to Ether, then we might lose some wei. Is that right?

Comment: @Ismael also here is using a floating point? https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Sending-ether

Comment: I said internal ether computations uses fixed point arithmetic. You get a fixed number of decimals digits. Given 1 wei is the smallest unit it cannot be divided into smaller parts using fixed point arithmetics. Outside solidity you can use floating point operations. But internally the EVM uses integer arithmetic. But you can use an external library that has floating point operations if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Wei is a basic unit, and Ether is just a convenient name for 10^18 Wei.  So all Ether amounts are integers when measured in Wei.